# C++, OpenCV ： 行列のサイズを大きくすると"Access violation reading location"エラーが出る

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

C++でOpenCVを用いてニューラルネットワークをトレーニングしたいです。

このエントリを参考にしました。　[参考サイト](http://kivantium.hateblo.jp/entry/2014/11/25/230658)

識別する画像は30*50の2値画像です。

訓練画像を読み込み、最後の列(INPUT+1)に教師信号(出力が1.0になってほしいニューロン)を付加して、1枚の画像を1行に出力し、csvファイルとしました。

---

グローバル定数は以下のように定義し、

```
const int TRAINING_SAMPLES = 300; //訓練データ数
const int INPUT = 30 * 50; // 入力次元
const int CLASSES = 10; //出力次元
```

学習データ、教師データは以下のように宣言しています。

```
//---学習データ---
cv::Mat trainingData(TRAINING_SAMPLES, INPUT, CV_32F);

//---教師データ---
cv::Mat trainingTeacher(TRAINING_SAMPLES, CLASSES, CV_32F);

//---データセットの読み込み---
readDataSet(filename, trainingData, trainingTeacher);
```

csvファイルから訓練データを読み込む関数です。

```
void readDataSet( char* filename, cv::Mat &data, cv::Mat &teacher)
{
    ifstream ifs(filename);
    if (!ifs)
    {
        cerr << "Error:Input data file not found" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    string str;
    stringstream ss;
    float csvData[TEST_SAMPLES][INPUT + 1];
    for (int row = 0; row < TEST_SAMPLES; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < INPUT; col++)
        {
            getline(ifs.seekg(0, ios_base::cur), str, ',');
            ss.str(str);
            ss >> csvData[row][col];
            ss.str("");
            ss.clear(stringstream::goodbit);
        }
        getline(ifs.seekg(0, ios_base::cur), str, '\n');
        ss.str(str);
        ss >> csvData[row][INPUT];
        ss.str("");
        ss.clear(stringstream::goodbit);
    }

//---学習データの読み込み---
    for (int row = 0; row < TRAINING_SAMPLES; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < INPUT; col++)
        {
            data.at<float>(row, col) = csvData[row][col];
        }
    }

//---教師データの読み込み---
    for (int row = 0; row < TRAINING_SAMPLES; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < CLASSES; col++)
        {
            teacher.at<float>(row, col) = 0.0;
        }
        int label = (int)csvData[row][INPUT];
        teacher.at<float>(row, label) = 1.0;
    }
}
```

---

`TRAINING_SAMPLES`が小さいとき(10くらい)は問題なく動いてくれるのですが、
`TRAINING_SAMPLES = 300`などとしたときはこの行で

```
data.at<float>(row, col) = csvData[row][col];
```

こんなエラーがでます。
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF7AB10D7F8 in NeuralNetwork.exe:        0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000D306604000.

メモリーが足らないのかとも思いますが、x64で開発していますし(環境設定はこのサイトを参考にしました。[環境設定](http://www.buildinsider.net/small/opencv/03))
Enable Large AddressesもYESにしましたが、直りませんでした。

Comment: `float csvData[TEST_SAMPLES][INPUT + 1];` としていますので、`csvData` はスタックに確保されているはずですが、`csvData` のサイズは単純計算でも 1.8M バイト程度になりますので、スタック領域に納まらないのでは？と思います。ただ、その場合は `Stack Overflow` というエラーメッセージが表示されるはずなので間違っているかもしれません。一応、`new` を使って `csvData` をヒープ領域に確保する様にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

argusさんも指摘されていますが、その付近、

> float csvData[TEST_SAMPLES][INPUT + 1];

が大きすぎます。また`TEST_SAMPLES`を使用して変数宣言していながらループの際には`TRAINING_SAMPLES`を使用されている点も気になります。

宣言したサイズを超えて変数アクセスした場合は、`Stack overflow`にはならずに`Access violation`になります。
Windows環境でVisual Studioを使用されているようですが、その場合、[コード分析](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/hh419384.aspx)を使用することで検出可能です。

大きすぎる変数に対しては次のような警告が出ます。

> warning C6262: Function uses '180136' bytes of stack:  exceeds /analyze:stacksize '16384'.  Consider moving some data to heap.

また境界を越えてアクセスし得る場合は次のような警告が出ます。

> warning C6201: Index '299' is out of valid index range '0' to '9' for possibly stack allocated buffer 'csvData'.

Comment: _またTEST_SAMPLESを使用して変数宣言していながらループの際にはTRAINING_SAMPLESを使用されている点も気になります。_
本当に初歩的な愚かな間違いを犯していました．解決しました．

Comment: @kamioka さん、間違いそのものは単純かもしれませんが、誰もがやらかすことだと思います。肝心なのは間違いを見つけるためにツールを使いこなすことかと。解決したのであれば、回答を承認していただけたら幸いです。